# Can I stop my Windows Antivirus Defender from deleting my OWN app?

Tags: windows-10, virus, anti-virus

I am learning python and I scripted and compiled my own executable for my personal use. This is just an app that I made to launch other apps, but this Windows Antivirus Defender keeps seeing it as a trojan and deletes it as if an app I made myself is going to kill my own pc. But I still want the antivirus to stay running in case if there is any other real virus. So, is there any way to stop the antivirus from getting rid of my app?

Comment: There must be something you are not saying. I've compiled many programs on Windows and Defender, over 15 years, has not touched one of them. It has never flagged one. Maybe you have changed it default settings. Anyway in settings you can exclude items.

Comment: Add you app to Windows Defender exclusion list.

Comment: My AV detected every test stub I ever wrote, because the name of the program was stub.exe and was a .net executable. They wanted me to submit every one of them for analysis through a tedious process. more trouble than it was worth.

Comment: I was able to submit a file last week to Microsoft and it took less than 30 seconds.  It’s fair easier than any other AV company makes it.  Microsoft even provides their analysis to you after the fact

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to stop Windows Defender from getting rid of my app?

Add it to your Windows Defender Exclusion list.

Under the latest version of Windows 10, as an administrator, you can:

1. Open **Windows Security**.
2. Select *Virus & threat protection* from the left-hand column.
3. Choose *Virus & threat protection setting → Manage settings*.
4. Scroll down and choose *Exclusions → Add or remove exclusions*.
5. Under *Exclusions*, press *+ Add an exclusion* and select the exclusion type (e.g. *file*).
6. From the standard Windows file selection dialog, choose your file and press *Open*.
7. The path to your file should now be listed under *Exclusions*.